# Instagram API: Get User's Info (on iOS)

Tags: xcode, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

My app is able to get the AccessToken after the user logs into Instagram, and Instagram calls back to my app.

I now want to get the user's information, most importantly his/her username.

All I have is the access token. I couldn't find a call that gives the current user's information without passing the {user-id} to it. For Example:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

How do you get this information with just the AccessToken (like Twitter, Facebook, Tumblr, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the user details for the current logged in user, use "self" as the user-id. For example:
 `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/`

Comment: can you explain it more ?

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=USER_TOKEN

`USER_TOKEN` is the token you received from instagram during authentication.

the official doc. [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self)

you first need `access_token` from instagram authentication api